# TYPO3 8.2: ViewHelper Namespace

Tags: namespaces, typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I have tried to create multiple ViewHelpers in a TYPO3 extension.

```
    <?php
namespace PdvPolymer\ViewHelpers;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractTagBasedViewHelper;

class ButtonUpViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractTagBasedViewHelper
{...
```

The ViewHelper is situated in the directory extension\Classes\ViewHelpers.

This works great when I call it with:

```
<div xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:p="http://typo3.org/ns/Extension/ViewHelpers">
<p:buttonUp></p:buttonUp>
</div>
```

But now I have tried to put the ViewHelper in a Sub-Directory like
extension\Classes\ViewHelpers\Custom.

The new namespace of the ViewHelper now is:

```
namespace Extension\ViewHelpers\Custom;
```

Now I call the ViewHelper with:

```
<p:custom.buttonUp></p:custom.buttonUp>
```

...and get an Error like:

```
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2016091908135339232bbd
```

My question is, what did I wrong?
The internal Fluid-Extension in TYPO3 does it all the same like me.
I have checked it!

Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 different issues.

First, I would suggest to avoid subdirectories in the namespace declaration and just use `xmlns:p="http://typo3.org/ns/Extension/ViewHelpers"`. Always add the subdirectory path when calling the ViewHelper then in the template, e.g.

```
 <p:custom.buttonUp></p:custom.buttonUp>
```

You don't need to the declaration twice.

2nd) About the error handling

Use the TypoScript `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` to turn it off for your development system and you will see a more helpful message. You can find more info in the [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#contentobjectexceptionhandler).

Comment: The first part is not really a answer, because I have done it this way. The second part is really nice thanks. My misstake was: i've two extensions on with the Viewhelper and a second with a template which uses the Viewhelper. Only when the extansion with the viewhelper was uninstalled and installed again, typo3 clear the viewhelper caches.